# Merge/Overwrite JS object with object derived as JSON from POST request

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I got the following obj that I use to store setting parameters. It holds default values I wanna make the properties of this obj be overwritten by a JSON that comes in via  POST request. Sure, I can convert every string value from the JSON indivually and assign it to the corresponing property, however, whats a good practise for that?

```
    const moth_eng = require('./fractioning_model_v1.1.js'); 

        // in ./fractioning_model_v1.1.js set default values
            var settings = {
                i: 1, 
                rev_share: 0.2, 
                parent_level_share: 0.45, 
                d: 2,
                get user_pool_share () {return this.i - this.rev_share;},
                get remaining_levels_pool () {return this.user_pool_share - this.parent_level_share;},
            };

        //main.js    
            app.post('/fractobj', function (req, res) {
              logger.log("info", "/fractobj requested - post")
              let obj = req.body;
              moth_eng.set_sttngs(obj);
              res.send(moth_eng.getFractions(10));
            });

        // in ./fractioning_model_v1.1.js
            function setSettings(obj){
                Object.assign(settings, obj);
            }
```

My Problem is, that the Object.assign() does assign the values as strings, since the values of the JSON are string and I find it uncool to individually convert those values for each value.

Whats a proper way to solve this problem in the big picture?

Comment: How are you getting the JSON data? Do you have access to the server side? Numbers should be fine in JSON and don't need to be quoted as strings.

Comment: This is node.js on the server side - see usage of express.js server.

Comment: So where is the server code that's preparing and sending the JSON? It should not be quoting numbers.

Comment: This is the server code. The JSON comes from the browser via POST